# How can I make this feature faster in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a highlight feature that will highlight anything contained in a `<p>` red using a user specified keyword. When the submit button is clicked Javascript/jQuery pull the keyword from the input field and compare it to any lines that conain it and then highlight those lines red. It works great... but its slow. Is there another way to do this that is faster when working with over 1000 lines of `<p>`?

HTML

```
Keyword:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="highlight_box" class="text_box" value="--Text--" /> &nbsp;
<input type="button" id="highlight" value="Highlight" />

<!--Print area for the Access log-->
<div id="access_content" class="tabbed-content">
<ul id="access-keywords-row" class="keywords-row">
    <!--When a user submits a keyword it is placed as a tag here so it can be deleted later-->
</ul><br /><br />
<div id="access_log_print" class="print-area">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p>Some more content</p>
    <!--Most of the time this could contain 1000's of lines-->
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
//add highlight and tag
$("#highlight").click(
function(){
    var id = $("#highlight_box").val();
    if(id == "--Text--" || id == ""){
        alert("Please enter text before highlighting.");
    }else{
        $("#access-keywords-row").append("<li><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" value=\"" + id + "\" /> " + id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>");
$("#access_log_print p:containsi(" + id + ")").css("color","red");        }
});

//remove highlight and tag
$(".keywords-row").on("click", ".delete_filter", 
    function() {
        var val = $(this).val();             

        //remove element from HTML
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#access_log_print p:containsi(" + val + ")").css("color","black");

    });
```

Comment: Are you working on a local machine?

Comment: Is the content of the `<p>` tags static?

Comment: Im sorry... I should have specified. I am working on a web application that is on a remote server.

Comment: If you add two filters that match a single row and then remove one of them this code will cause to remove the highlighting

Comment: remove jQuery. Hand optimize your dom manipulation code. Hand optimize your HTML structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding color, red means adding the style attribute to each p, I think this can be improved adding a class:

```
p.highlight {
   color:red;   
}
```

And replacing

```
$("#access_log_print p:contains(" + id + ")").css("color","red");
```

by

```
$("#access_log_print p:contains(" + id + ")").addClass('highlight');
```

This probably speeds a little bit the process

Comment: not using a stupid `:contains` selector is going to speed things up

Comment: And what is he going to use then? Do you have a better solution Raynos?

Comment: See my alternative answer which does not use the "stupid" contains ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8934948/69442

Comment: My better solution would be to fix his entire HTML structure and rework his javascript completely. I decided I couldn't be bothered to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a css class, e.g.:

```
.red{background-color:#f00;}
```

and then instead of adding to each `"style=background-color:#f00;"` you will just `.addClass("red");`

just less code to put, but still jQuery will have to go thru all lines and if it is a lot then I guess it depends on your machine speed ;)

Comment: Good idea... I will give that a shot. Maybe it will speed it up a little. The machine I use to develop is just that... not meant for speed, so I expect it to be slow. When I put it in production it should handle fine considering it is a corporate web server that is super powerful.

Comment: I made a fiddle and tried it out, using a class instead of styles cut the time by 50-75%, 30-50 ms without class vs 10-20 ms with, when searching for "Some". Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/EYqEa/

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter how fast the webserver is when you're writing JavaScript code - all javascript is executed locally, on the end users machine. Not the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small solution using jQuery's `contains()` method. Obviously you can throw in some string validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/W2CZB/

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will probably increase performance at the cost of space. It works by building a word mapping of the lines and accessing directly to add or remove the highlight class. This solution also keeps a count of the number of times a filter hit that line so it stays highlighted until the last filter is removed. I have tested with a few lines, I am not sure how will it perform with 1000s. You tell us :)

```
$(function(){

buildIndex();

$("#highlight").click(
function(){
    var id = $("#highlight_box").val();
    if(id == "--Text--" || id == ""){
        alert("Please enter text before highlighting.");
    }else{
        var filter = $("<li><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" value=\"" + id + "\" /> " + id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>");
        filter.click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
            removeHighlight(id)
        });
        $("#access-keywords-row").append(filter);
        $.each(index[id], function(i,line){
            if (line.highlightCount)
              line.highlightCount++;
            else {
              line.addClass('highlight')
              line.highlightCount=1;
            }
        });
    }
});

function removeHighlight(id) {
    $.each(index[id], function(i,line){
        line.highlightCount--;
        if (line.highlightCount<1)
            line.removeClass('highlight')
    });
};
});

var index={};
function buildIndex(){
    $("#access_log_print p").each(function(i) {
        var line = $(this)
        var words = line.text().split(/\W+/);
        $.each(words, function(i,word){
            if (!index[word]) { index[word]=[]; }
            index[word].push(line);
        });
    });
}
```